# "Bad Content Type" using Curl with GAE Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, blobstore

I'm using `blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')` to generate a url for a POST request that I will send a jpeg. App engine returns a URL correctly. Given the URL I've been using curl to post the picture but I keep getting "Bad content type.  Please use multipart" returned.

Does anybody have any ideas how to deal with this? I searched a bit and didn't find a whole lot.

Curl command: `curl -X POST -d @download.jpg --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" LINK_FROM_GAE`

Edit: I also tried 
`curl --form "fileupload=@download.jpg" --header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" LINK_FROM_GAE`
without any luck.